# Replacing all non-alphanumeric + punctuation characters with empty strings

Tags: java, regex, talend

I'm working on a regular expression in Talend inside a tReplace component

I'm moving data from Oracle to Redshift and I'm having issues with DDL length because some characters are not supported (I guess)

I have product names like

> 175/65 R14 Efficiency +

> XXX N°  5 H7DC

And they have to stay like this.
But sometimes I have NBSP inside labels or even worse sometimes

I saw this list of punctuation online
[!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_{|}~°]

and I need to add it to my already existent Regex "[^A-Za-z0-9]"

**TLDR**; Can someone help me writing a REGEX to replace everything in a column except
[A-Za-z0-9] and the punctuation list above ?
It must be able to be use in the following code (As I'm using Talend and it's java interpreted)

> StringUtils.replaceAll(row1.label, "[^A-Za-z0-9]", "");

Comment: You can use `[^\\p{Alnum}]|\\p{Punct}`

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I tried it but unfortunately it replace spaces and also "-" or "&" "+" so I used `[^\\p{Alnum}\\p{Punct}]

But it stills remove spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding the solution thanks to the help of the answers above.

I used :

> [^\p{Alnum}\p{Punct}\s]